# How to equalize the spaces above and below the theorem?

Tags: spacing, theorems

When I use the following code,

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\makeatletter
 \def\ps@spheadings{\ps@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\normalfont\scriptsize
  \rlap{\thepage}\hfil \leftmark{}{}}%
  \def\@oddhead{\normalfont\scriptsize
  \rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\thepage}}%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\partmark{\@secmark\markboth\partrunhead\partname}%
  \def\chaptermark{%
    \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
  \def\sectionmark{%
    \@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\sectionname}%
}
\def\th@spplain{%
  \let\thm@indent\relax
  \thm@headfont{\bfseries}% heading font bold face
  \let\thmhead\thmhead@plain \let\swappedhead\swappedhead@plain
  \thm@preskip.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip
                                \@minus.2\baselineskip
  \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
  \normalfont
}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{spplain}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\pagestyle{spheadings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
$\\$Beginning Text.
\begin{theo}
Some Text
\end{theo}
Ending Text.
\end{document}
```

I get the following output, [image]

but I want to have an output in which the followings hold,

> 1. The "**E**" "**Ending Text**" should be along the same vertical line as "**B**" of "**Beginning Text**".
> 2. The space between "**Theorem 1**" and "**Beginning Text**" should be equal to that of "**Theorem 1**" and "**Ending Text**".

How can I modify the above code (or produce a different code) to meet this criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist\@endpetrue }
```

before `\makeatother` would suffice, it automatically suppresses paragraph indentation. Alternatively, you can simply add `\noindent` after every `\end{theo}`.

The vertical space (between baseline) before and after **Theorem 1.** should already be equal, since you have set

```
\thm@postskip\thm@preskip
```